# How to check if an asynchronously loaded script has finished loading in javascript

Tags: javascript, yepnope, dynamic-script-loading

Using javascript to asynchronously download another javascript file.

I understand that this can be done by inserting a new script tag onto the page with the `src` attribute set to the file url.

I also need to run some code when the script is finished downloading. I've been using [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) for this and they provide "callbacks" that execute when the script has finished downloading and executing.

How is this accomplished?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most JS loaders do this via injecting an `<script>` tag to the DOM, and binding its `onload` event to your provided function.

`yepnope` uses the same approach, and you may simply observe that from its [source code](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/master/yepnope.js). The function `injectJs` creates a DOM element using `doc.createElement`, sets `src` and other needed attributes using `setAttribute`, binds the `onreadystatechange` & `onload` event to the provided callback, and finally inserts the element into the document.

Answer (score 3):

`yepnope.injectJs( scriptSource [, callback ] [, elemAttributes ] [, timeout ]);`
Straight off [their website](http://yepnopejs.com/): You simply run the code you need to in the successful callback like so.

```
// Example
yepnope.injectJs("jquery.js", function () {
  console.log("It is finished loading and I can do whatever I need to here");
}, { charset: "utf-8" }, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that I can't use yepnope for this.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow then why would you tag this question with the `yepnope` tag?

Comment: @jessegavin - I tagged in that way because I mentioned yepnope in the question.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done using jquery, if u want to use it, [Jquery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

checkout the link it gives detail information about it.